# How to store passwords in the database (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

While making my first major project, I have encountered a problem. I need to store passwords in a database. I know about hashing using bcrypt and salting, but I don't know how to properly store them in the database (what type of data to use). Should I use BINARY, BLOB or VARCHAR? After hashing I have both password hash and salt as bytes. I'm using Mariadb as the database

Comment: I usually use PostgreSQL as a database, but mariadb is not bad as well, I think you should store it as a simple varchar. Because I think, hashing with bcrypt makes all stuff for you I mean, hashed password with bcrypt is already in safe

Comment: @AbdusamadAbdullakhanov I don't worry about safety in this case, I just don't know can hash or salt contain non-unicode characters

Comment: 1) BINARY types can safely contain any byte value. However, you probably want to use VARBINARY instead, because BINARY is padded with 0x00 bytes. 2) BLOB types have a 40 byte overhead per row, because they allow a row to have more data. 3) If you convert your bytes value to hex, you can safely keep that in a VARCHAR. Python has a library method to do this. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) For example, Django does it this way.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) wikipedia page the output is 59 or 60 depending on the cost. output is in a radix-64 with `$` as separators.

Like Nick ODell said the comments `VARBINARY(60)` keeps the simple format easily. A `VARCHAR(60)` is also an ok choice with `ascii` or `latin1` as a character set.

Due to the variable length a `VARCHAR(60)` corresponds to the maximum length without worrying about handling if the cost is 1 byte or 2.