# Want to validate user input and compare it to my database

Tags: python, html, flask, stored-procedures, mariadb

I want to validate user input to make sure it's in my database. Right now, I'm implementing this with a stored procedure that will return a 1 if everything matches and a 0 if something is wrong.

If I call the stored procedure in the database, it works perfectly. But when I call it from my python file, it always fails.

```
@app.route('/iniciarsesion', methods=['POST'])
def sessiousuario():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    _email=request.form['email']
    _pass=request.form['password']
    valido= cursor.callproc('iniciosesion',(_email, _pass))
    if valido==1:
        return "Bienvenido"
    else:
        return "Esta Cuenta no existe"
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
MariaDB [GameExchange]> CREATE PROCEDURE iniciosesion(IN app_email varchar(50), IN app_pass varchar(50))
    -> BEGIN
    -> IF (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Usuario WHERE Email= app_email AND Password= app_pass)) THEN SELECT 1;
    -> ELSE
    -> SELECT 0;
    -> END IF;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

When I return the variable "valido" directly instead of my message, it returns whatever I put in the email input. This tells me it's not working, but I don't know where the failure is.

```
@app.route('/iniciarsesion', methods=['POST'])
def sessiousuario():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    _email=request.form['email']
    _pass=request.form['password']
    valido= cursor.callproc('iniciosesion',(_email, _pass))
    if valido==1:
        return "Bienvenido"
    else:
        return valido
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

I can also provide the table of the database and my HTML form, in case the problem is there:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Email    | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
<form action="/iniciarsesion" method="POST" id="registro">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <br><br>
    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
  </form>
```

I'm working in a Google Cloud console.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you go too far, store passwords a [non-reversible hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74058610/how-to-store-passwords-in-the-database-python) like [bcrypt](https://www.makeuseof.com/encrypt-password-in-python-bcrypt/) rather than clear text. After than, you just retrieve the password hash via email.

Comment: [Cursor.callproc](https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/cursor.html) doesn't return the elements. There are other functions like `fetchone` for that (also its a tuple not a single value).